# Aligning background image for a div element in css

Tags: html, css, web, background-image, css-position

So I am new to css,and have been trying to develop a basic website as a college project,but I am having problems aligning the background image for a div with class name mainhead,it leaves a whitespace at left of the screen.
Whatever width I set it to,there is a blank white space on the left.

I dont know what to do,I havent set any padding or margins and also specified left: 0px,but no joy.
The class I am having problem with is the mainhead class
Here is the code,please help!

```
.loginbox
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1370px;
    height: 40px;
}
.loginbut
{
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    font-family: "Avant Garde",Avantgarde,"Century Gothic",CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-color: #2C2C2C;
    border-radius: 8px;
    top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none !important;
}
.loginbut:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
.mainhead
{
    background-image: url("grey.jpg");
    background-repeat: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family: "Avant Garde",Avantgarde,"Century Gothic",CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
    top: 40px;
    width: 1360px;
    height: 170px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-align: center;
}
.mainhead h1
{
    font-family: "Avant Garde",Avantgarde,"Century Gothic",CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to have some HTML in it so I can see how the CSS in linked to your site?

Comment: Are you removing the default margin on body? `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: try using background-size:100% 100% for mainhead class

Answer (score 0):

Use background-position: center center; and background-size: cover; and remove width from mainhead. Hope it should work

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Answer (score 0):

Try using this reset code by Eric Meyer [enter link description here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and also set the .mainhead div to 100%.